# Is it possible to upgrade from a Beta Release to a Final Release?

Tags: upgrade, updates, release-management, beta

If I install a new beta release now (e.g. 15.10 beta-2), one week before the Final Release of this version, will I be able to update/upgrade it regularly to the Final Release version when it comes out or do I have to reinstall the system completely?

This question refers to the cd-image system of the releases: Are the Beta images basically the same as the Final Release, just with yet to be released improvements and updates, or will the Final Release image be an entirely different file so that the beta installations become obsolete and a full reinstallation is necessary to obtain the release version?